# quantile groupby pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by, quantile

I have below pandas dataframe. I want to create a new column that would give me 75% quantile rate groped by State and County

below code gives me only 75% quantile rate as output, i want to create a new column with 75% quantile rate in the existing df

df = df.groupby('State')['rate'].quantile(0.75)

| State | county | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AK | a | 27.5 |
| AK | a | 30.5 |
| GA | a | 35.5 |
| GA | b | 50.0 |
| GA | b | 75.5 |
| GA | c | 90.5 |
| AR | a | 16.5 |
| AR | a | 10.5 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function:

```
df['q'] = df.groupby('State')['rate'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.75))
```

If need also `county`:

```
df['q'] = df.groupby(['State', 'county'])['rate'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.75))
print (df)
  State county  rate       q
0    AK      a  27.5  29.750
1    AK      a  30.5  29.750
2    GA      a  35.5  35.500
3    GA      b  50.0  69.125
4    GA      b  75.5  69.125
5    GA      c  90.5  90.500
6    AR      a  16.5  15.000
7    AR      a  10.5  15.000
```

EDIT: If possible some missing values:

```
df['q'] = (df.fillna({'State':'missing', 'county':'missing'})
            .groupby(['State', 'county'])['rate'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(0.75)))
```

Comment: thanks ! I am getting below error with the code. Any idea how to solve for it? I am new to python, your help is very appreciated       ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8532 elements, new values have 20651 elements

Comment: @AmberBahia - Can you check `EDIT` ?

Answer (score 1):

Or with `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame` and `pd.MultiIndex.map`:

```
df['new'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['State', 'county']]).map(df.groupby(['State', 'county'])['rate'].quantile(0.75))
```

And now:

```
>>> df
  State county  rate     new
0    AK      a  27.5  29.750
1    AK      a  30.5  29.750
2    GA      a  35.5  35.500
3    GA      b  50.0  69.125
4    GA      b  75.5  69.125
5    GA      c  90.5  90.500
6    AR      a  16.5  15.000
7    AR      a  10.5  15.000
>>>
```

Comment: @AmberBahia Read, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers